# .NET Use Dto models in Infrastructure

Tags: c#, .net, dto, clean-architecture, mediator

i try do app with clean architecture (with mediator, fluent validation). I have services (interfaces) in application project and implementation in infrastructure project. Is it ok use in the services as parameter the Dto objects? I save dto in application project. Or right way is use entities in domain project?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use `DTOs` from the application layer in the infrastructure layer.

Comment: Yea i mean have dtos in application layer and use it from infrastructure layer. So that's ok?

Comment: Yes, it's ok. @PetrKasnal